# How to make a layout template in Sinatra?

Tags: templates, layout, sinatra

I'm new to Sinatra and I can't figure out where to put my application layout.

I've seen the inline method that uses

```
# app code    
__END__

@@layout
  %html
    = yield
```

But I'd like the layout to be in it's own `.haml` file.

What should the layout file be named? What directory should it be placed in?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you haven't already, create a folder where your sinatra script lives called...

```
views/
```

and put your layout in there, call your layout

```
layout.haml
```

or whatever extension (e.g. `.erubis`) you'd like to use.

Answer (score 27):

### Automatic Wrapping

To make every view default to be wrapped in a layout, create a file in `views/layout.haml` and your calls to `haml :myview` will automatically be wrapped in this layout.

### Skipping the Layout

If you want a particular view rendering not to use the layout, use:

```ruby
get '/' do
   # Other pages will use layout.haml, but not the main page
   haml :home, :layout => false
end
```

### Using a Different Layout

If you want to use a layout other than the common layout, create another file (for example `views/admin_layout.haml`) and then pass this as an option:

```ruby
get '/admin/create' do
   haml :create, :layout => :admin_layout
end
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `undefined local variable or method \`layout' for ` when I use the layout option, please help me

Comment: it worked if I changed the ` - ` to underscore ` _ ` i.e, `admin_layout` please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190208/nameerror-in-using-custom-layout-option-in-sinatra-app

Comment: @pahnin My mistake; thank you for pointing that out. FWIW if should work if you did `:layout => :"admin-layout"`, but better to simply use a name that is easily represented as a symbol literal. I have updated my answer.