# HAML Pass partial dynamically to layout in Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I am trying to build a Sinatra app with HAML and use a layout to be able to break my site down into partials:

**layout.haml**

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        = partial :head
    %body
        = partial :header
        = partial :#{@template}
        = partial :footer
```

Where my Sinatra app is calling `layout.haml` like so:

```
get '/test' do      
    @template = "\"test/index\""

    haml :"layout"
end
```

To try to pull in:

```
views/
|----test/
    |----_index.haml
```

Which gives me the error:

> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)

I have also tried redefining a number of different combinations with no success:

```
@template = ":\"test/index\""
= partial #{@template}

@template = "test/index"
= partial :#{@template}
```

Note: I am using [Sinatra Partials](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial)

Am I going about this entirely the wrong way? My brain is really suffering trying to figure out how to employ HAML for such a basic concept of DRY templating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah it was so simple afterall.. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190297/how-to-make-a-layout-template-in-sinatra), I realized now of course that everything is wrapped with `layout.haml` and I simply needed to place the appopriate `yield` statement.

**layout.haml**

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        = partial :head
    %body
        = partial :header
        = yield
        = partial :footer
```

And call the template as usual:

```
get '/test' do    
    haml :"test/index"
end
```